# Spark Streaming Writing Data To Kafka Topic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write a data frame to Kafka topic inside for each RDD.
I am using  below code:

```
 mesg.foreachRDD(rdd => { Dataframe.write.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","host")
    .option("subscribe","topic")
    .option("principal","Kerberos-principal")
    .option("keytab","kerberos-keytab")
    .save()
    })

enter code here
```

I am getting null pointer exception. Specifically I need to write a data frame to Kafka Topic. Can anyone help on this. Note Dataframe here is obtained after converting rdd to dataframe and removing some fields from input json sent to Kafka Topic.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283) at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java309) at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229) at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)`

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace... Why cant you use `mesg.write.format("kafka")`? What is `Datframe`?

Comment: Dataframe is the variable containing reduced fields of json input and is of spark DataFrame type.

Comment: That answers one of my questions, what about the other? Please [edit] with the full stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283) at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java309) at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229) at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)

Comment: No part of your shown code is using regex. Again [edit] the question, not use comments to provide more details

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception was due to config error which has been resolved. For wrting dataframe to kafka topic from RDD please follow the below approach:

```
import sparkSession.implicts._

val df = Original Dataframe.select(col("one column name"),to_json(struct($"*"))).toDF("key","value")

df.write.format("kafka").option("bootstrap-server-properties",value from config).option("topic",value from config).save()
```

Comment: Note the entire code block should be within foreachRDD.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you want to avoid hard coding of column name in select statement then follow this approach:

val df = Original Dataframe.select(to_json(struct($"*"))).as("value").selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")

df.write.format("kafka").option("bootstrap-server-properties",value from config).option("topic",value from config).save()

Comment: Since this isn't a direct answer to your question, I think these additional details would be best placed in your original answer; you can do this be editing your accepted answer. This will help others to see this additional information as the accepted answer will be more visible.